# Get Wordpress gallery images via page ID

Tags: php, wordpress, gallery

I have a page within WordPress called 'Gallery', the page ID is 128, and I need to display only the gallery images from that page on a different page with a different ID. The images were uploaded using the standard WordPress gallery functionality.

I've been trying to use `get_children` and a `foreach` loop to achieve it, but I can't seem to get only the gallery images from the page I need (ID 128).

Here's what I have so far:

```
$images = get_children( array( 
    'post_parent'    => 128, 
    'post_type'      => 'attachment', 
    'post_mime_type' => 'image', 
    'orderby'        => 'menu_order', 
    'order'          => 'ASC'
) ); 
if ( $images ) { 
    // looping through the images
    foreach ( $images as $attachment_id => $attachment ) {
        echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, 'full' );
    }
}
```

How can I display gallery images from a WordPress page, on a different page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ended up being solved by [Nate Allen](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/32698/nate-allen) over at the WordPress stack exchange.

this is in my functions.php:

```
function na_get_gallery_image_urls( $post_id ) {

    $post = get_post($post_id);

    // Make sure the post has a gallery in it
    if( ! has_shortcode( $post->post_content, 'gallery' ) )
        return;

    // Retrieve all galleries of this post
    $galleries = get_post_galleries_images( $post );

    // Loop through all galleries found
    foreach( $galleries as $gallery ) {

        // Loop through each image in each gallery
        foreach( $gallery as $image ) {

            echo '<img src="'.$image.'">';

        }

    }

 }
```

And calling it on my page with this:

```
<?php na_get_gallery_image_urls(128); ?>
```

128 being the ID of the page with the Gallery attached.